# How can I install QT on Lion 10.7.3 with XCode 4.3 installed?

Tags: qt, osx-lion, homebrew

I'm having problems installing QT on my MacBook with Lion 10.7.3 and XCode 4.3.1 installed.  I tried to install with brew, and got a compiler error.  Below is the end of the error, and the "brew doctor" output.  It seems to be using the wrong version of gcc... although I just installed the latest XCode.  Any ideas?  I'm trying to install QT, so I can run headless browser tests with capybara-webkit.  (I also tried with --install-from-source and got the same error.)

> gstroup$ brew install qt
>
> ....
>
> kernel/qcocoaview_mac.mm:1386:61: error: cannot initialize a parameter of type 'NSString *' with an lvalue of type 'const NSString *'
>           return [[[NSAttributedString alloc]  initWithString:tmpString] autorelease];
>                                                               ^~~~~~~~~
>   /System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Headers/NSAttributedString.h:28:34: note: passing argument to parameter 'str' here
>   - (id)initWithString:(NSString *)str;
>                                    ^
>   2 errors generated.
>   make[2]:*  [.obj/release-shared/qcocoaview_mac.o] Error 1
>   make[1]:  *[release] Error 2
>   make: *** [sub-gui-make_default-ordered] Error 2
>   ==> Exit Status: 2
>   http://github.com/mxcl/homebrew/blob/master/Library/Formula/qt.rb#L76
>   ==> Environment
>   /usr/bin/gcc
>   HOMEBREW_VERSION: 0.8
>   HEAD: 64e489663add868db679cca2186ff8d7796e5d9e
>   HOMEBREW_PREFIX: /usr/local
>   HOMEBREW_CELLAR: /usr/local/Cellar
>   HOMEBREW_REPOSITORY: /usr/local
>   HOMEBREW_LIBRARY_PATH: /usr/local/Library/Homebrew
>   Hardware: 8-core 64-bit dunno
>   OS X: 10.7.3
>   Kernel Architecture: x86_64
>   Ruby: 1.8.7-249
>   /usr/bin/ruby => /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/bin/ruby
>   Xcode: 4.3.1
>   GCC-4.0: N/A 
>   GCC-4.2: build 401 (5664 or newer recommended)
>   LLVM: build 2336 
>   MacPorts or Fink? false
>   X11 installed? true
>   ==> Build Flags
>   CC: /usr/bin/cc => /usr/bin/clang
>   CXX: /usr/bin/c++ => /usr/bin/clang
>   LD: /usr/bin/cc => /usr/bin/clang
>   CFLAGS: -O3 -w -pipe
>   CXXFLAGS: -O3 -w -pipe -fvisibility=hidden
>   MAKEFLAGS: -j8
>
> Error: Failed executing: make 
>   Please report this bug: https://github.com/mxcl/homebrew/wiki/new-issue
>
> Also try:
>     `brew doctor` to check your setup for common problems.
>     `brew missing` to check installed packages for missing deps.
>
> gstroup$ brew doctor
>
> /usr/bin/gcc
>   Your gcc 4.2.x version is older than the recommended version. It may be advisable
>   to upgrade to the latest release of Xcode.
>
> We couldn't detect gcc 4.0.x. Some formulae require this compiler.
>
> /usr/bin is in your PATH before Homebrew's bin. This means that system-
>   provided programs will be used before Homebrew-provided ones. This is an
>   issue if you install, for instance, Python.
>
> Consider editing your .bashrc to put:
>     /usr/local/bin
>   ahead of /usr/bin in your $PATH.
>
> Some brews install binaries to sbin instead of bin, but Homebrew's
>   sbin was not found in your path.
>
> Consider editing your .bashrc to add:
>     /usr/local/sbin
>   to $PATH.
>
> /usr/bin/gcc
>
> gstroup$ gcc --version
>
> i686-apple-darwin11-llvm-gcc-4.2 (GCC) 4.2.1 (Based on Apple Inc. build 5658) (LLVM build 2336.9.00)
>   Copyright (C) 2007 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
>   This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
>   warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

Answer (score 0):

Xcode 4.3.x switched away from gcc as the compiler. Now Apple uses llvm. This maybe the root of your issue. There is a Github project https://github.com/kennethreitz/osx-gcc-installer/downloads that will let you download a gcc compiler.

You may have to prefix your brew command with `env CC=/usr/bin/gcc` to specify the gcc compiler.